# Append to String at certain position

Tags: java

I have a String miscFlag which is of size 100. I need to append to this miscFlag starting from  index 20 as 0-19 are reserved for some other info. And then append subsequently at certain positions only. Can we do this using StringBuilder/StringBuffer?

This is how i am trying to do it..

```
    StringBuilder info = new StringBuilder(miscFlag);
    info.append(" ");
    info.append(Misc.toTimestampLiteral(currentDate));//append this from pos 20
    info.append(" ");
    info.append(formattedStartTime);  //append this from pos 40
```

Here i am not able to specify the position from where to append.

Comment: You can use: `info = info.substring(X, Y) + "BLABLA" + //SO ON`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the insert method.

```
info.insert(19, Misc.toTimestampLiteral(currentDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `String#subString` to cut 0 to 20 index and then add new String.

```
String str = miscFlag.substring(0,20)+ " "+Misc.toTimestampLiteral(currentDate)+" "+  miscFlag.substring(21);
```

Comment: It should be `substring` (case sensitive)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed length fields are doable with `StringBuilder` but looks for me very clumsy and error-prone, I would not recommend. Use [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), it is exactly for that you need - to create string where field widths and positions are important:

```
 String.format("A[%8s][%4s]", "ab","cd");
```

will result

```
 A[      ab][  cd]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the sposition where you'd like to insert as below

```
StringBuilder info = new StringBuilder(miscFlag);
info.insert(19, Misc.toTimestampLiteral(currentDate) + " ");
info.insert(39, formattedStartTime + " ");
```